# Proper convert from excel to csv

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, csv

I have a excel (.xls) with 1 sheet (Sheet1) and I want to convert that into csv using python 3. I found this code:

```
import xlrd
import csv


def csv_from_excel():
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook('safir/fisier-safir.xls')
    sh = wb.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
    your_csv_file = open('safir.csv', 'w')
    wr = csv.writer(your_csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    for rownum in range(sh.nrows):
        wr.writerow(sh.row_values(rownum))

    your_csv_file.close()

csv_from_excel()
```

But the problem with this is that this approach will not preserve Excel formatting of certain numbers, 1 will become 1.00, 001 -> 1.0, 0,9 ->1, and all of this format problems, if I do the conversion excel -> csv manually I won't found this issues, and I got similar issues with others script also, do someone have a proper one ? Thank you!

Comment: hav you tried with `cell(x,y)`? there must be a way to get the actual text.

Comment: does `pandas.read_excel(filename, dtype='str, convert_float=False)` have the correct number formatting? Excel stores all numbers as floats, so rounding etc can change/act weird

Comment: Note, in Python 3.x you should open your file with `newline=''` if you are using a `csv.writer()`. This wont fix your problem though.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the below code. It's keep the formatting as is

```
import win32com.client
xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.DisplayAlerts = False
xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename='C:\\pscript\Copy.xlsx',ReadOnly=1)
wb = xl.Workbooks(1)
print(wb)
wb.SaveAs(Filename='C:\\pscript\out.csv', FileFormat='6') #6 means csv
wb.Close(False)
xl.Application.Quit()
wb=None
xl=None
print("done")
```